# Reshaping sequence for GRU keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

I have a dataset made of 100.000 90 length sequences of 3 dimensions (100.000x90x3) to predict if the sequence contains one over 5 types of errors.

I would like to train a GRU network but I would like the sequences to be chopped into 10 length arrays (10x3). Each 90x3 sequence would be divided into 9 10x3 sequences and then used to train the model.

I would like to know how to configure the Reshape layer to obtain these sequences.